# Extract a string from a another column using regexp_extract

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, extract

I want to get data of s[0] from "column1":

```
sada/object=fan/sn=dadfs/s[0]=gsf,sdfs,sfdgs,/s[1]=dfsd,sdg,hte,/redirect=sdgfd/
```

Output should be values of s[0]

```
gsf,sdfs,sfdgs
```

I was trying to do using `\` and it's not working

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(column1, 's\\[0\\] = ([^&]+)')
```

This is in PySpark.

Comment: Something like `REGEXP_EXTRACT(column1,'s\\[0\\]=(.*?),/', 1)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Its just giving me empty string

Comment: Well, it [should work](https://regex101.com/r/jgk4kw/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Spark dataframe:
df = spark.createDataFrame([("sada/object=fan/sn=dadfs/s[0]=gsf,sdfs,sfdgs,/s[1]=dfsd,sdg,hte,/redirect=sdgfd/",)], ["column1"])

# SQL table:
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
```

PySpark:

```py
df.select(F.regexp_extract('column1', r's\[0\]=(.*?),/', 1).alias('match')).show()
# +--------------+
# |         match|
# +--------------+
# |gsf,sdfs,sfdgs|
# +--------------+
```

SQL:

```py
spark.sql("select regexp_extract(column1, r's\\[0\\]=(.*?),/', 1) as match from df").show()
# +--------------+
# |         match|
# +--------------+
# |gsf,sdfs,sfdgs|
# +--------------+
```